# heroku run locally command give me the following error in node js ,what are the possible reason?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'start' ]

2 info using npm@6.4.1

3 info using node@v10.15.0

4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]

5 info lifecycle btc@1.0.0~prestart: btc@1.0.0

6 info lifecycle btc@1.0.0~start: btc@1.0.0

7 verbose lifecycle btc@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle btc@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program

Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-

bin;C:\Users\THOR\Desktop\btc\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files

Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Program

Files\nodejs;C:\Program

Files\Git\bin;c:\windows\system32;C:\Users\THOR\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windo

wsApps;C:\Users\THOR\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\THOR\AppData\Local\Programs

\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin

9 verbose lifecycle btc@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\THOR\Desktop\btc

10 silly lifecycle btc@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'app.js' ]

11 silly lifecycle btc@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null

12 info lifecycle btc@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script

13 verbose stack Error: btc@1.0.0 start: `app.js`

13 verbose stack Exit status 1

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program

Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program

Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)

13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)

13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit

(internal/child_process.js:251:5)

14 verbose pkgid btc@1.0.0

15 verbose cwd C:\Users\THOR\Desktop\btc

16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134

17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program

Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"

18 verbose node v10.15.0

19 verbose npm  v6.4.1

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 1

22 error btc@1.0.0 start: `app.js`

22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the btc@1.0.0 start script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional

logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: can you post your start script

Answer (score 0):

**12 info lifecycle btc@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script**

Go to your package.json and add your start script like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "script": "node app.js"
}
```